How to embed flutter app in other web app on different server
I am trying to embed my flutter app (web) into another website.
I have read the flutter docs about it. But I am not qutie sure how to do it.
I have webspace A where I have uploaded my built flutter-app.
Now I also have webspace B where another webpage is hosted. On this webpage B I want to embed my flutter-app into a div-element.
Is this possible? If yes, how?
How can I reference my built app correctly? When building my flutter web app I get this script:
(()=>{var L=()=>navigator.vendor==="Google Inc."||navigator.agent==="Edg/",W=()=>typeof ImageDecoder>"u"?!1:L(),E=()=>typeof Intl.v8BreakIterator<"u"&&typeof Intl.Segmenter<"u",P=()=>{let s=[0,97,115,109,1,0,0,0,1,5,1,95,1,120,0];return WebAssembly.validate(new Uint8Array(s))},p={hasImageCodecs:W(),hasChromiumBreakIterators:E(),supportsWasmGC:P(),crossOriginIsolated:window.crossOriginIsolated};function u(...s){return new URL(S(...s),document.baseURI).toString()}function S(...s){return s.filter(t=>!!t).map((t,i)=>i===0?_(t):j(_(t))).filter(t=>t.length).join("/")}function j(s){let t=0;for(;t<s.length&&s.charAt(t)==="/";)t++;return s.substring(t)}function _(s){let t=s.length;for(;t>0&&s.charAt(t-1)==="/";)t--;return s.substring(0,t)}function b(s,t){return s.canvasKitBaseUrl?s.canvasKitBaseUrl:t.engineRevision&&!t.useLocalCanvasKit?S("https://www.gstatic.com/flutter-canvaskit",t.engineRevision):"canvaskit"}var h=class{constructor(){this._scriptLoaded=!1}setTrustedTypesPolicy(t){this._ttPolicy=t}async loadEntrypoint(t){let{entrypointUrl:i=u("main.dart.js"),onEntrypointLoaded:r,nonce:e}=t||{};return this._loadJSEntrypoint(i,r,e)}async load(t,i,r,e,n){n??=o=>{o.initializeEngine(r).then(l=>l.runApp())};let{entryPointBaseUrl:a}=r;if(t.compileTarget==="dart2wasm")return this._loadWasmEntrypoint(t,i,a,n);{let o=t.mainJsPath??"main.dart.js",l=u(a,o);return this._loadJSEntrypoint(l,n,e)}}didCreateEngineInitializer(t){typeof this._didCreateEngineInitializerResolve=="function"&&(this._didCreateEngineInitializerResolve(t),this._didCreateEngineInitializerResolve=null,delete _flutter.loader.didCreateEngineInitializer),typeof this._onEntrypointLoaded=="function"&&this._onEntrypointLoaded(t)}_loadJSEntrypoint(t,i,r){let e=typeof i=="function";if(!this._scriptLoaded){this._scriptLoaded=!0;let n=this._createScriptTag(t,r);if(e)console.debug("Injecting <script> tag. Using callback."),this._onEntrypointLoaded=i,document.head.append(n);else return new Promise((a,o)=>{console.debug("Injecting <script> tag. Using Promises. Use the callback approach instead!"),this._didCreateEngineInitializerResolve=a,n.addEventListener("error",o),document.head.append(n)})}}async _loadWasmEntrypoint(t,i,r,e){if(!this._scriptLoaded){this._scriptLoaded=!0,this._onEntrypointLoaded=e;let{mainWasmPath:n,jsSupportRuntimePath:a}=t,o=u(r,n),l=u(r,a);this._ttPolicy!=null&&(l=this._ttPolicy.createScriptURL(l));let m=WebAssembly.compileStreaming(fetch(o)),c=await import(l),w;t.renderer==="skwasm"?w=(async()=>{let d=await i.skwasm;return window._flutter_skwasmInstance=d,{skwasm:d.wasmExports,skwasmWrapper:d,ffi:{memory:d.wasmMemory}}})():w={};let f=await c.instantiate(m,w);await c.invoke(f)}}_createScriptTag(t,i){let r=document.createElement("script");r.type="application/javascript",i&&(r.nonce=i);let e=t;return this._ttPolicy!=null&&(e=this._ttPolicy.createScriptURL(t)),r.src=e,r}};async function T(s,t,i){if(t<0)return s;let r,e=new Promise((n,a)=>{r=setTimeout(()=>{a(new Error(`${i} took more than ${t}ms to resolve. Moving on.`,{cause:T}))},t)});return Promise.race([s,e]).finally(()=>{clearTimeout(r)})}var v=class{setTrustedTypesPolicy(t){this._ttPolicy=t}loadServiceWorker(t){if(!t)return console.debug("Null serviceWorker configuration. Skipping."),Promise.resolve();if(!("serviceWorker"in navigator)){let o="Service Worker API unavailable.";return window.isSecureContext||(o+=`
The current context is NOT secure.`,o+=`
Read more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Secure_Contexts`),Promise.reject(new Error(o))}let{serviceWorkerVersion:i,serviceWorkerUrl:r=u(`flutter_service_worker.js?v=${i}`),timeoutMillis:e=4e3}=t,n=r;this._ttPolicy!=null&&(n=this._ttPolicy.createScriptURL(n));let a=navigator.serviceWorker.register(n).then(o=>this._getNewServiceWorker(o,i)).then(this._waitForServiceWorkerActivation);return T(a,e,"prepareServiceWorker")}async _getNewServiceWorker(t,i){if(!t.active&&(t.installing||t.waiting))return console.debug("Installing/Activating first service worker."),t.installing||t.waiting;if(t.active.scriptURL.endsWith(i))return console.debug("Loading from existing service worker."),t.active;{let r=await t.update();return console.debug("Updating service worker."),r.installing||r.waiting||r.active}}async _waitForServiceWorkerActivation(t){if(!t||t.state==="activated")if(t){console.debug("Service worker already active.");return}else throw new Error("Cannot activate a null service worker!");return new Promise((i,r)=>{t.addEventListener("statechange",()=>{t.state==="activated"&&(console.debug("Activated new service worker."),i())})})}};var y=class{constructor(t,i="flutter-js"){let r=t||[/\.js$/,/\.mjs$/];window.trustedTypes&&(this.policy=trustedTypes.createPolicy(i,{createScriptURL:function(e){if(e.startsWith("blob:"))return e;let n=new URL(e,window.location),a=n.pathname.split("/").pop();if(r.some(l=>l.test(a)))return n.toString();console.error("URL rejected by TrustedTypes policy",i,":",e,"(download prevented)")}}))}};var g=s=>{let t=WebAssembly.compileStreaming(fetch(s));return(i,r)=>((async()=>{let e=await t,n=await WebAssembly.instantiate(e,i);r(n,e)})(),{})};var I=(s,t,i,r)=>(window.flutterCanvasKitLoaded=(async()=>{if(window.flutterCanvasKit)return window.flutterCanvasKit;let e=i.hasChromiumBreakIterators&&i.hasImageCodecs;if(!e&&t.canvasKitVariant=="chromium")throw"Chromium CanvasKit variant specifically requested, but unsupported in this browser";let n=e&&t.canvasKitVariant!=="full",a=r;n&&(a=u(a,"chromium"));let o=u(a,"canvaskit.js");s.flutterTT.policy&&(o=s.flutterTT.policy.createScriptURL(o));let l=g(u(a,"canvaskit.wasm")),m=await import(o);return window.flutterCanvasKit=await m.default({instantiateWasm:l}),window.flutterCanvasKit})(),window.flutterCanvasKitLoaded);var U=async(s,t,i,r)=>{let e=u(r,"skwasm.js"),n=e;s.flutterTT.policy&&(n=s.flutterTT.policy.createScriptURL(n));let a=g(u(r,"skwasm.wasm"));return await(await import(n)).default({instantiateWasm:a,locateFile:(l,m)=>{let c=m+l;return c.endsWith(".worker.js")?URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([`importScripts('${c}');`],{type:"application/javascript"})):c},mainScriptUrlOrBlob:e})};var k=class{async loadEntrypoint(t){let{serviceWorker:i,...r}=t||{},e=new y,n=new v;n.setTrustedTypesPolicy(e.policy),await n.loadServiceWorker(i).catch(o=>{console.warn("Exception while loading service worker:",o)});let a=new h;return a.setTrustedTypesPolicy(e.policy),this.didCreateEngineInitializer=a.didCreateEngineInitializer.bind(a),a.loadEntrypoint(r)}async load({serviceWorkerSettings:t,onEntrypointLoaded:i,nonce:r,config:e}={}){e??={};let n=_flutter.buildConfig;if(!n)throw"FlutterLoader.load requires _flutter.buildConfig to be set";let a=d=>{switch(d){case"skwasm":return p.crossOriginIsolated&&p.hasChromiumBreakIterators&&p.hasImageCodecs&&p.supportsWasmGC;default:return!0}},o=(d,C)=>{switch(d.renderer){case"auto":return C=="canvaskit"||C=="html";default:return d.renderer==C}},l=d=>d.compileTarget==="dart2wasm"&&!p.supportsWasmGC||e.renderer&&!o(d,e.renderer)?!1:a(d.renderer),m=n.builds.find(l);if(!m)throw"FlutterLoader could not find a build compatible with configuration and environment.";let c={};c.flutterTT=new y,t&&(c.serviceWorkerLoader=new v,c.serviceWorkerLoader.setTrustedTypesPolicy(c.flutterTT.policy),await c.serviceWorkerLoader.loadServiceWorker(t).catch(d=>{console.warn("Exception while loading service worker:",d)}));let w=b(e,n);m.renderer==="canvaskit"?c.canvasKit=I(c,e,p,w):m.renderer==="skwasm"&&(c.skwasm=U(c,e,p,w));let f=new h;return f.setTrustedTypesPolicy(c.flutterTT.policy),this.didCreateEngineInitializer=f.didCreateEngineInitializer.bind(f),f.load(m,c,e,r,i)}};window._flutter||(window._flutter={});window._flutter.loader||(window._flutter.loader=new k);})();
//# sourceMappingURL=flutter.js.map

It references some files like main.dart.js, flutter_service_worker.js ... could I just somehow fix the paths so it takes them from webspace A?
Until now I just used an IFrame to show my app. But I guess that using the embedded feature would be more smooth. I am just a bit puzzled on how to do this.
Thanks!

https://geekyants.com/blog/flutter-element-embedding

@AbuHurairah this is sadly an old approach. Flutter embedding has changed a lot afaik.

Thanks for the idea; it introduces to me the embedded mode in Flutter.

We use nextjs to embed flutter in this way, and we can use that as a React component
import Head from 'next/head';
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import styles from '../styles/PurpleLoader.module.css';
import useWebviewUserAgent from './useWebviewUserAgent';

function loadMainDartJs(elem: HTMLDivElement) {
  const scriptTag = document.createElement('script');
  scriptTag.src = 'webspaceA..../main.dart.js';
  scriptTag.type = 'application/javascript';
  elem.append(scriptTag);
}

const FlutterApp: React.FC = () => {
  const ref = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  const shouldLoadDartJs = useRef(true);
  const { isWebview } = useWebviewUserAgent();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (ref.current && shouldLoadDartJs.current && typeof window !== 'undefined' && !isWebview) {
      shouldLoadDartJs.current = false;

      loadMainDartJs(ref.current);
      
    }
  }, [isWebview]);

  return (
    <>
      {isWebview ? (
        <Loader />
      ) : (
        <>
          <Head>
            <base href="/" />
          </Head>
          <div ref={ref} className={styles.flutterAppContainer} />
        </>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default FlutterApp;


Thank you for your effort. I don't completely understand your answer though. I am not using react. Where do you do the loading of the flutter engine etc.?

I'll explain what we have,
we have an application in Nextjs
We have the Flutter repository in the root of our Nextjs application and we simply reference it within Nextjs using this:
function loadMainDartJs(elem: HTMLDivElement, buildNumber: string) {}.
Although this post may be useful for your case:
https://medium.com/@lucas.goldner/flutter-element-embedding-unleashing-the-power-of-integrating-flutter-apps-into-websites-e91c84c13f2d
